# How to Reach QEMU VM's with IP Address (Optionally Static)?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm

###### Situation

I have two QEMU KVMs (named *master* and *worker*, respectively) running on my laptop. The VMs use the headless server edition of Ubuntu 22.04, and the laptop is running Mint.

###### Goal

I want three IP addresses or names (host and the two VM's) that I can use to connect to any of them from another, and all ports of these three should be visible to the others, as I am trying to experiment with some kubernetes concept with this mini setup. I do not want to resort to port forwarding.

###### Optional

Best if the IP addresses are static, so that I do not have to look them up at each reboot of the laptop.

I tried looking up the QEMU networking documentation, and it does give me a lot of information, but as my networking fundamentals are not good, I was wondering if there is a relatively straightforward way to set this up.

Comment: In essense, use a bridge. The bridge can be the master of a physical NIC, or not. If you use libvirt, the VM is probably using a bridge already. (Although libvirt has some default firewall rules for the bridge; I don't remember if they could prevent the host from reaching the guest "actively".) If you want static IP, just configure it so inside your guest.

Comment: Once you got the bridge it's as simple as `-nic bridge,br=bridge_name`. (Probably want to add the flag that sets the MAC as well; and `bridge_name` needs to be added to a whitelisting conf (IIRC `/etc/qemu/bridge.conf`). If you aren't using libvirt *and* does not enslave a physical NIC to the bridge either, you'll need to create and configure the bridge, configure IP forwarding and NAT yourself. (But enslaving a bridge to a physical NIC means that the VM will be part of the physical network / LAN.)

Comment: Too late and tired for me to go into details at the moment, but, in a nutshell, use a bridge.  If you don't want port forwarding, I think you may want a rather full setup that imposes the least restrictions/limits.  So what you'll want to do is to have a virtual network card on the host system, which can communicate virtually with the Qemu machines.  To create a virtual network card on the host system, see about creating a TUN device and/or a TAP device.

Answer (score 0):

> I want three IP addresses or names (host and the two VM's) that I can use to connect to any of them from another, and all ports of these three should be visible to the others, as I am trying to experiment with some kubernetes concept with this mini setup. I do not want to resort to port forwarding.

One necessary thing to point out is that "port forwarding" (NAT) is **not** what makes packets go, in general. Rather, it's an additional tool – a workaround for certain problems – that can be applied *after* packets are already being forwarded by a router.

Your home router uses NAT for one reason, Kubernetes uses it for another reason, but in both cases it's only used for a specific reason where regular IP routing won't do. In your case, regular IP routing would do fine and "port forwarding" shouldn't even enter the picture at all.

> I tried looking up the QEMU networking documentation, and it does give me a lot of information, but as my networking fundamentals are not good, I was wondering if there is a relatively straightforward way to set this up.

In the most straightforward option, with `-net tap`, QEMU gives you a 'tap#' network interface for each VM – you can treat them exactly like two Ethernet ports that directly connect to two machines.

You can configure those Ethernet (tap) interfaces in two ways: either as two independent subnets (with your host machine acting as a *router* between them) or as a single subnet (with your host machine acting as a *bridge* aka switch between them).

<sup>(That is to say that you *should* brush up on your network fundamentals, as then it would become apparent that "1 host, 2 VMs" equals pretty much the simplest "1 router, 2 computers" setup; everything else that e.g. libvirt might do is optional stuff that gets layered on that.)</sup>

**Bridging** is generally the much simpler option as it has little to no configuration that needs to be enabled; it's like having everything connected to the same Ethernet switch. You'll probably have to create an empty bridge manually if you aren't using libvirt (which creates a 'virbr0' for you), but afterwards QEMU's `-net bridge` (instead of '-net tap') will automatically add the VM's 'tap' interface into it.

A bridge itself doesn't care about IP but usually you'll want to assign 'br0' an address so that the *host OS* could participate in the network and talk to the VMs. Libvirt does that automatically when it creates the 'virbr0' bridge.

**Routing** is slightly more complex as it needs to be enabled on the host OS system-wide (via "IP forwarding" sysctl), and then you need to make sure the host system's firewall (iptables) permits forwarding. Once it's enabled though, assign *each* non-bridged 'tap' interface its own IP address from a different subnet (no overlapping) and it'll work.

(It's possible to have a mix of both; e.g. you can create two bridges, each with multiple VMs, and route between bridges.)